# How to Change the Order of TradingView Header Buttons

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I have added a chart reset button to the existing header buttons using the following code:

I am facing an issue where I want the reset button to be positioned in front of the previously created buttons.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
let initialState = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '445',
    interval: '1D',
    symbol: coin_type + "_" + market_type,
    timezone: "Asia/Seoul",
    debug: false,
    container: "graph_view",
    library_path: "/chart2/charting_library/",
    locale: "ko",
    custom_css_url: '/css/exchange/chart.css',
    enabled_features: ["keep_left_toolbar_visible_on_small_screens"],
    disabled_features: [
        "use_localstorage_for_settings",
        "header_symbol_search",
        "header_compare",
    ],
    datafeed: {}
}

let widget = new TradingView.widget(initialState);
```

I learned from the documentation how to create a reset button in the header. However, this button always goes to the back.

```
widget.headerReady().then(function() {
    var button = widget.createButton();
    button.setAttribute('title', 'reset');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Initial widget setup
        initializeWidget();
    });
    button.textContent = 'reset';
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Research CSS `z-index` property. It will be easier to target if you also add to your javascript, after `button.setAttribute(etc)`, another instruction: `button.id = "someUniqIDName"` and use that in your CSS